# Hibernate -> ArrayList cannot be cast to Set

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist, set, classcastexception

I have a Java EE application and I use Hibernate. The domain objects, I changed the List / ArrayList to Set / HashSet, because it is better to use Sets.

But in my Dao implementation I run into a problem:

```
public Set<Person> getAllPersons() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session sess = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Transaction tx = sess.beginTransaction();
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Set<Item> items = (Set<Item>) sess.createQuery("from Item").list();
    tx.commit();

    return items;
}
```

Here I get an error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Set
```

What can I do to avoid this error?

Thank you in advance & Best Regards.

Comment: Are you sure that you know what the difference between a set and a list is? Because in no way is it 'better' to use a Set. You use Sets whenever you want a single instance of an object in your collection, whereas you can have multiple instances of the same object in a list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
List<Item> list = sess.createQuery("from Item").list();
Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(list);
```

`sess.createQuery("from Item").list();` will return a array list of resulting items, if you need it in Set you can make it as shown in code

Comment: or rebuild the database which might not be an option

Comment: minor issue, it should be `Set<Item> items = new HashSet<Item>(list);`. Apart from that: +1

Comment: "rebuild the database which might not be an option" - This makes no sense, `Query.list()` always returns a `List`: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/javadoc/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()

Comment: @mattb the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

> The domain objects, I changed the List / ArrayList to Set / HashSet, because it is better to use Sets.

It's not "better" to use `Set`, it depends entirely on what you need. But anyway, the collection type you use in your domain objects and the return type of [`Query#list()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#list()) are **two unrelated things**.

Personally, I can't say that I see much value in converting the result of a query into a `Set` (apart from eating more memory), unless you explicitly want to remove [duplicates from query results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560239/is-it-valid-for-hibernate-list-to-return-duplicates) of course (but in that case, I would challenge the mappings).

Now, if you insist, the various `Set` implementations have a constructor that takes a `Collection` (and the question is essentially a duplicate of [Easiest way to convert a List to a Set? - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429860/easiest-way-to-convert-a-list-to-a-set-java)).

Comment: When I need help with JPA/HSQL you are nowhere to be seen, but you appear! outrageous :)