# Hibernate doubles results?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an extraordinary weird error with Hibernate and I'm unable to figure out why and when it occurs.

For any reason sometimes (There aren't any exceptions in my Server-Logs - plus: I can't reproduce it) if I am using Hibernate for displaying hierarchical data the elements in the lower level are doubled.
I have a list of the group-items and save their joined rows in a list within every group-entity-class.
The group-list works fine - I never had any issues with it, but the element-list doubles its objects sometimes.

For example - if my database looks like:

```
|agrupID|Name|
------------------
|01     |Good-Selling|
|02     |Weak-Selling|

|ID|agrup_ID_FK|Information|Price|
----------------------
|01|         01|Product A  |10.00|
|02|         01|Product B  | 7.00|
|03|         02|Product C  |50.00|
|04|         02|Product D  | 8.50|
```

Hibernate outputs:

```
|01 |Good-Selling|
|02 |Weak-Selling|

|01|   01|Product A  |10.00|
|01|   01|Product A  |10.00|
|02|   01|Product B  | 7.00|
|02|   01|Product B  | 7.00|
|03|   02|Product C  |50.00|
|03|   02|Product C  |50.00|
|04|   02|Product D  | 8.50|
|04|   02|Product D  | 8.50|
```

After I actualize the page with F5 the error is gone.

In the beginning I thought maybe I am running the same output twice in those cases but after going throught the HTML-Code I realized everything was as it should be. Well, except the double results...

The reason is definitively Hibernate. In one part of the program it happened far too often, so I've decided to move back to plain JDBC instead of Hibernate. Since then it never occurred again.

I am using JSP, Apache 7 Server and the database is located on a SQL-Server 08. Hibernate is hibernate-core:3.6.10.Final.

My code is just the code I copied from the tutorials, it works fine in 99% of the cases...
This is how I load the groups which contain the lists of elements. Every time the page is reloaded I fetch it again:

```
private List<Pricegroup> material;

public void loadAPGroupsHibernate() throws HibernateException {
        try {
            SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
            Statistics stats = factory.getStatistics();
            stats.setStatisticsEnabled(true);
            Session session = factory.openSession();
            Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "SELECT G FROM productGroups.ProductGroup G order by G.agrupID";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            material = query.list();
            System.out.println("Listsize: " + material.size()); //The size here is fine
            tx.commit();
            apgruppenhibernateini = true;
        } catch (HibernateException hibex) {
            System.err.println("Persistenzen, APGruppen: " + hibex);
            System.err.println(hibex.getMessage());
            hibex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The output doesn't seem to be spectacular too... As I told you, it works usually.

```
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
            for (ProductGroup bg : material) {
ret.append("<table><tr>");
                ret.append("<td>").append(bg.getName()).append("</td>\n");
                ret.append("<table><tr>");
ret.append("<td>Information</td><td>Price</td>");
                ret.append("</tr>");
                for (productGroups.Prices aps : bg.getPrices()) {
                    ret.append("<td>").append(aps.getInformation()).append("<td>");                    
                    ret.append("<td>").append(aps.getPrice())).append("<td>");

                    ret.append("</tr>");
                }
                ret.append("</table>");
            }

            return ret.toString();
        }
```

The Entity-Classes are also pretty simple:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Dbank].[dbo].[Pricegroup]")
public class Pricegroup implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "AGrupID")
    private Integer agrupID;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "agrup_ID_FK", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Prices> prices;

    public Pricegroup() {
    }
//Boring Setters and getters
}
```

The lower entity class...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[Dbank].[dbo].[Prices]")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)
public class Prices implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private String information;       
    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Double price;

    private String colorcode;
    @JoinColumn(name = "agrup_ID_FK", referencedColumnName = "agrupID")
    private Integer agrup_ID_FK;

    public Arbeitspreise() {
    this.colorcode="FFFFFF";
    }
//more boring getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can you enable hibernate logging and see what is the query that gets executed to fetch the results? Before F5 and after F5? And execute them directly on your database to see if the results differ? This will eliminate any relationship related errors without much restarts of the app and we can focus on where the problem actually is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it valid for Hibernate list() to return duplicates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560239/is-it-valid-for-hibernate-list-to-return-duplicates)

Comment: If a collection can't have doubles you should define it as `Set` instead of `List`. This won't solve a potential mistake in your code but it will get rid of the duplicates.

Comment: @prabugp - if that was so easy I would have done it already. I'm unable to tell when it happens and several users are using the program at the same time. Tell me how I can reproduce it...

Comment: @Bart - In the other part of the program which was replaced meanwhile Sets were used.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - haven't seen that. I'll go through it, thanks!