# JpaRepository behaves differently with Stream<T> and List<T> return types regarding duplicates?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In a project, there is a large jpa query like

```
@Query( "select foo from FooEntity
    left join fetch foo.bars bars
    join fetch bars.baz "
      /** ca 10 more entities with join fetch and left join fetch" */
    "where" /** some conditions */
    "order by foo.id")
Stream<FooEntity> getFoos()
```

Now I tried changing it to `List<FooEntity>` (as the client only called `collect(toList())`), but it breaks some tests, it contains duplicates. When using `Set<FooEntity>`, it behaves the same way as with `Stream<FooEntity>`.

Without going into details about the large query, it is "ok", expected behaviour or may this indicate some bug in the query?

I also looked at some questions like [Is it valid for Hibernate list() to return duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560239/is-it-valid-for-hibernate-list-to-return-duplicates), but are there any differences between `Stream`, and `List`, which may be defined in some spec?

The SQL generated by Hibernate is BTW the same for all return types

Comment: Might be good to have `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG` and `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE` to see how your query is rendered by hibernate and editing your question to reflect.

Comment: @hd1: the query does not change; it is the same for `Stream`, `List`, and `Set`

Comment: Can you show the query, though?