# Hibernate Set Or List

Tags: hibernate, list, set

Can anybody know when to use Set and when to use List in hibernate mapping file ?

```
<set name="" table="">
    <key>
        <column name="" />
    </key>
</set>


<list name="" cascade="all">
    <key column="" />
    <index column="" />
    <one-to-many class=""/>
</list>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [@OneToMany List<> vs Set<> difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562673/onetomany-list-vs-set-difference)

Answer (score 17):

Take a look at this post: [@OneToMany List<> vs Set<> difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562673/onetomany-list-vs-set-difference)

The main difference is that a list has ordering while a set does not. Also, a set cannot have duplicate values, while a list can.

Answer (score 0):

1. we cannot assign duplicate value in Set but we can assign in List
2. Insertion order not preserved in Set but preserved in List