# Hibernate Set or List

Tags: java, hibernate

In Hibernate Entities, in what cases is it the better to use List, as opposed to Set?

### Example of Set

```
public class Department {

  private Long departmentId;

  private Set<Employee> employees;

  // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

### Example of List

```
public class Department {

  private Long departmentId;

  private List<Employee> employees;

  // Getter and Setter methods
}
```

Comment: My personal opinion : I prefer sets becauses they automatically remove duplicates.

Comment: For     Set    
public class A {    
  private Long aId;    
  private Set<B> bS;    
  // Getter and Setter methods    
}    
    
For     List    
public class A {    
  private Long aId;    
  private List<B> lB;    
  // Getter and Setter methods    
}

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements - in this case I suppose `Set` would be more suitable because I don't think duplicated employees should exist in department.

IMHO basic rule is - if you allow duplicates use `List`, otherwise use `Set`.

Comment: For     Set    
public class A {    
  private Long aId;    
  private Set<B> bS;    
  // Getter and Setter methods    
}    
    
For     List    
public class A {    
  private Long aId;    
  private List<B> lB;    
  // Getter and Setter methods    
}

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that a list has ordering while a set does not. see [Hibernate Set Or List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188718/hibernate-set-or-list)