# Hibernate many-valued association best practices

Tags: java, list, hibernate, set, hibernate-mapping

There are many questions on stackoverflow that speaks about using `List` vs `Set` in Hibernate entities. My question is slightly different (or may be same, but I am not able to understand it yet).

If I read the Hibernate docs, they recommend to use `Set` for many-valued associations here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes-equalshashcode.

```
Quoting from above documentation link:

 You have to override the equals() and hashCode() methods if you:

 - intend to put instances of persistent classes in a Set (the recommended way to represent many-valued associations); 
 - and intend to use reattachment of detached instances
```

That was till Hibernate 4.3. But in later versions, I don't see that statement anymore (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-model-pojo-equalshashcode)

So my questions are

- why did Hibernate recommended to use `Set` instead of `List` till Hibernate 4?
- Since I don't see that recommendation in Hibernate 5, does it mean that it is not valid anymore?

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think there is just a single rule what you should do, but the usage is depending on your need. I suggest reading this, but you probably already did - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562673/onetomany-list-vs-set-difference

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I read that question, and some others too. I also agree that there isn't just a single rule. I am trying to understand why exactly Hibernate recommended the usage of Sets. I believe there should be some reason behind such a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Well to answer your first question:

> why did Hibernate recommended to use Set instead of List till Hibernate 4?

I will start by pointing out the main differences between `List`and `Set`:

- `List` is an ordered collection while `Set` is not, but note that while `List` is an ordered collection, it won't be ordered if no index column is specified in your object.
- `Set` doesn't allow duplicates while `List` does.

And this second point is what explains the recommendation of using `Set` upon `List`, even if [Hibernate documentation itself says that **lists and bags are more efficient than sets**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-collections-mostefficentinverse).

In fact the problem with using `List` in bi-directional relationships is that *when you merge operation is called on the parent association it inserts duplicate children*, which seems to be [**a bug** in older Hibernate versions](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5855), you can read more about this problem on:

[**Hibernate Facts: Favoring bidirectional Set(s) vs List(s)**](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-facts-favoring-sets)

And to answer your second question:

> Since I don't see that recommendation in Hibernate 5, does it mean that it is not valid anymore?

We can't make a deduction in this fact but I think this bug is fixed on Hibernate 5 that's why we don't see this recommendation anymore, but it's just an *assumption*.