# Bind a set in a spring form

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp

I am trying to bind a spring form with a set in the command object.

In my command class **AInstance** I defined set as

```
private Set<BParameter> bParameters = new HashSet<BParameter>();
```

In jsp I bind it as

```
<form:input path="bParameters " />
<form:input path="bParameters " />
```

As its a Java **Set** so there may be many fields. When I submit this form I tried to get **Set** as:

```
Set<BParameter> bParameters = aInstance.getBParameters();
```

I got **Set** with a 0 size.

I also tried to bind as

```
<form:input path="bParameters[${itemsRow.index}].bParmvalues[0].parmValue" />
```

but got exception

```
Invalid property 'bParameters[0]' of bean class
```

What is the problem with my binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an List in the controller.

In the view you can use this straight html (not sure if this works with spring tags).

```
<input name="bParameters[{idx}].bParmvalues[0].parmValue" />
```

Comment: By using List<> instead of Set<> in controller. Problem solved.

Comment: It's more like a workaround. If you work directly on your JPA objects through the form this is not possible. It should not be necessary to workaround this but I haven't been able to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

Its going to be an array, which Spring will translate into a `List`; it will also instantiate the `List` implementation - you don't need to do that in your `Command` object.  Try using

```
private List<String> bParameters;

public void setBParameters(List<String> bParameters) {
    this.bParameters= bParameters;
}
public List<String> getBParameters() {
    return bParameters;
}
```

in your `Command` object.  Those values are probably coming in as Strings.

Comment: By using List<> instead of Set<> in controller. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have problems binding as

```
 private Set<Types> typeses = new HashSet<Types>(0);


  <form:textarea path="typeses" style="width:200px;height:150px"/>
```

I use Spring 3.5. The only problem with this is, that it leaves []-marks on the field for some reason

Comment: I would like to know that too! :)

Comment: You mean all the fields in your form or what?

Comment: When I bind a path for a field e.g <form:input path="bParameters[${itemsRow.index}].bParmvalues[0].parmValue" /> []-mark diappears. Similarly I bind my all fields and get rid of []-mark.

Comment: Can you still tell me where you get itemsRow ja ParmValue attributes? Are they attributes of objects that your set hold?

Comment: I could not understand your question. itemsRow is a loop counter in jsp which can be set in for-each tag as varStatus="itemsRow">. Hope it may help you.

Comment: So I think its different for me, because I use texarea. Each word written, separated with comma should be a set instance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find a way to bind Set into form parameters. However other solutions suggesting to "use list instead" is not good enough for me because if the field is part of JPA one-to-many relationship with eager fetching, [using List will cause duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1995244/179630)

Hence the best solution I find so far is by posting the form as JSON -- using Ajax -- instead. Here's how in JQuery:

```
var person = // .. construct form object here

$.ajax(url, {
  method : 'post',
  contentType : 'application/json',
  data : JSON.stringify(person)
});
```

Note that you need to mark the contentType as `application/json`

On the controller side, you can bind this to a Java object by using `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public void save(@RequestBody Person person) {
  ..
}
```

More info here: https://gerrydevstory.com/2013/08/14/posting-json-to-spring-mvc-controller/