# How to bind a Set<CustomObject> in spring mvc form

Tags: java, forms, spring, jsp

I have a command object associated with a spring form controller:

```
public class PluginInstance {
  private Set<PluginParameter> pluginParameters = new HashSet<PluginParameter>();
  ... some other string/long properties and getter setters...
}
```

the PluginParameter also have a Set in it which contain the values

```
public class PluginParameter {
  private String parmName;
  private Set<PluginParmvalue> pluginParmvalues = new HashSet<PluginParmvalue>();
  ...some other string/long properties and getter setters...
}
```

(Normally the pluginParmvalues will contain only one value, a list have been used for future expandability)

In the spring form I binding the values as

```
<form:input path="pluginParameters[${itemsRow.index}].pluginParmvalues[0].parmValue" />
```

but the thing is that there can be a form:select(to present multiple predefined options to the user) or form:input (user can input any value). This has to be decided from another object

```
public class PluginConfigParm {
  private String parmName;
  private ArrayList<String> choices;
  ...getter setters and other properties
}
```

where I have to compare the name of PluginConfigParm.paramName with PluginParameter.paramName when they match and PluginConfigParm.choices.size() > 0 then form:select will be shown populated with the values from PluginConfigParm.choices otherwise form:input will be shown.

The question is simple: How can I do that.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819616/bind-a-set-in-a-spring-form

Comment: the problem is same but there are two possible solutions I am thinking, please help me if you understand my problem, I am messing it up badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using List<> instead of Set<> in controller. Problem solved. May be Set<> has no getter/setter that can be bind with spring form.

So `<form:input path="pluginParameters[${itemsRow.index}].pluginParmvalues[0].parmValue" />`
and List<> in controller makes my life easier.

Answer (score 0):

The Set is not an indexed collection so I could not work by using this syntax

```
pluginParameters[${itemsRow.index}].pluginParmvalues[0].parmValue
```

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
class person{
set name<string> = new HashSet<String>()
}


<input type="hidden" path="person.name" name="person.name" value="<%=valueStr%>"/>
take valueStr = "hello, world"
```

by giving it as comma seperated values.. set works

Its working for me