# Spring MVC, Form Control for a List of non selectable elements

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

As the title stated, i was wondering if there is an HTML element for handling a list of non-selectable elements) and how i can use it with Spring MVC. A list of non-selecteable elements is a kind of control that acts as holder of multiple separated values, in fact, described in functional terms, we can thing on a select with multiple="true" with all of his elements selected by default, so all the values are sent to the controller on the {{onSubmit}}. I don't renember is there was a name for that kind of control and if exists in HTML standart FORM (i guess no). (*)

For example, suppose that we have a View (called view.jsp), that uses a Bean (called Bean.java) that is created and populted by a controller (called Controler.java, sorry for the cheaps names :D). Let's assume for simplicity that all the wiring stuff is done.

**Bean.java**

```
Class Bean {
   Collection<String> values;

   // setters and getters
}
```

**view.jsp**

```
<form:select path="values" items="${values}" /> // (*) the idea is here use the right component, not a select, because a select excludes some values, and i want all values!
```

**Controller.java**

```
protected ModelAndView onSubmit(final HttpServletRequest request,
      final HttpServletResponse response, final Object command,
      final BindException errors) throws Exception {
      Bean bean = (Bean) command;

      bean.getValues();
      // do my bussiness-model stuff
}
```

Well thanks to everyone who read this!

And greetings for all!

Victor.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not just using disabled (non editable) input fields with the same name? You can also see here [how to bind collections with spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819616/bind-a-set-in-a-spring-form).

Comment: mmmmm, i see Vlad, Thanks for the answer.. but i really don't understand the correct answer of that post!

Comment: You have to put n `<form:input path="values"/>` fields in your form.