# Hibernate - entity with collection

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity like this (any unnecessary code omitted):

```
class Client{
    private id;  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Remark> remarks = new HashSet<Remark>();
    //getters and setters
}
```

I call List clients = session.createCriteria(Client.class). If Client has multiple remarks, I get multiple the same Client objects, for example if Client has 2 remarks, then in list there are two the same clients. I don't think this is good behaviour, am I missing something?

Comment: It's difficult to determinate the problem with this block of code. Can you post the entire relation between Client and Remarks? and how you initialize the client list.

Comment: This is expected behavior. See this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995080/hibernate-criteria-returns-children-multiple-times-with-fetchtype-eager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that you have to use `criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);`
to get what you want. Look at the link pasted by nsfyn55.

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't look like you are using HQL but in the interest of completeness another way to solve this is using the `distinct` keyword in HQL. I am reasonably sure that an HQL query like the one below will also solve your problem.

```
select distinct c from Client c where c.id = ?
```