# Join Fetch for One To Many relationship is returning same entity multiple times

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, hql, jpql

I have the following mapping
1 User can have 0 or more roles.

Query 
from User u JOIN Fetch u.roles

If User1 has two roles RoleA and RoleB. 
Then User1 is returned twice.

What i expect is User1 should be returned Once with list of roles containing RoleA and RoleB 
How can I fix this.

Also please explain behavior for Many To Many relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the JPA spec 4.4.5.3

```
SELECT d FROM Department d LEFT JOIN FETCH d.employees WHERE d.deptno = 1
```

> A fetch join has the same join semantics as the corresponding inner or
>   outer join, except that the related objects specified on the
>   right-hand side of the join operation are not returned in the query
>   result or otherwise referenced in the query. Hence, for example, if
>   department 1 has five employees, the above query returns five
>   references to the department 1 entity.

Options

1. You can add a `DISTINCT` to the `SELECT` clause to filter out the
   duplicate rows.
2. Define an `EntityGraph` for the query and add the `roles` field to it,
   and it will be fetched, meaning you omit the `"FETCH JOIN"` from the query.
3. Mark the `roles` field as EAGER, but this would then apply to all fetching of that field, so likely not desirable.

Comment: Thanks for Entity Graph tip.
Please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507887/behavior-of-distinct-root-entity

Comment: A coworker showed me that you might want to add .setHint("hibernate.query.passDistinctThrough", false) to the named query with 'DISTINCT' for performance reasons, as described here (https://vladmihalcea.com/jpql-distinct-jpa-hibernate/)

Answer (score 2):

user below code :

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

For more details check this link:
[Hibernate Criteria returns children multiple times with FetchType.EAGER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995080/hibernate-criteria-returns-children-multiple-times-with-fetchtype-eager)

Comment: What happens if I have User -> Role -> Permission all many to many.
Will criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY); return the result as expected ?