# Traversing ORM relationships returns duplicate results

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have 4 tables -- `store, catalog_galleries, catalog_images, and catalog_financials`.

When I traverse the relationship from `store --> catalog_galleries --> catalog_images` in other words: `store.getCatalogGallery().getCatalogImages()` I get duplicate records. Does anyone know what could be the cause of this? Any suggestions on where to look?

The `store` table has a `OneToOne` relationship with `catalog_galleries` which in turn has a `OneToMany` relationship with `catalog_images` and an eager fetch type. The `store` table also has a `OneToMany` relationship with `catalog_financials`.

Below are the relevant entities:

Store entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="store")  
public class Store {
    ...
    private CatalogGallery gallery;
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="store")
    public CatalogGallery getGallery() {
        return gallery;
    }
}
```

CatalogGallery entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="catalog_galleries")  
public class CatalogGallery {
    ...
    private Store store;
    private Collection<CatalogImage> catalogImages;
    ...
    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public Store getStore() {
        return store;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="catalogGallery", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Collection<CatalogImage> getCatalogImages {
        return catalogImages;
    }
}
```

CatalogImage entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="catalog_images")  
public class CatalogImage {
    ...
    private CatalogGallery catalogGallery;
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="gallery_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    public CatalogGallery getCatalogGallery() {
        return catalogGallery;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not enough information, please provide your JPA classes with mappings. Have you tried to look at generated SQL?

Comment: Are all the records duplicates? Have you checked your join columns for duplicate entries?

Comment: Yes, all the records have a duplicate. In `catalog_images` there are multiple entries that have the same value in the `join` column and that is to group the related data/images.

Comment: So, you have duplicated records in the database, right? Also, why do you need `insertable=false, updatable=false` in join column?

Comment: @axtavt: The database itself does NOT have duplicate records; however, one field among the columns of `catalog_images` may have the same value and that is to group the fields. For example two rows in the table would be similar to -- 1 1 comp & 2 1 cat5 -- the first column is id, the second is gallery_id, and the third is name. gallery_id is the join column and some rows may have the same value for this column. As for the need of insertable=false, updatable=false, I'm not quite sure myself; when I ran the code I was shown an error message that indicated I needed to add those stipulations

Answer (score 5):

This is because of your `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`. 
Hibernate creates JOINs and tries to get all your collections with one query. 
If you really need `FetchType.EAGER` and don't want to replace your collection with Set you can use `@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)` annotation for your collection:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="catalogGallery", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
public Collection<CatalogImage> getCatalogImages {
    return catalogImages;
}
```

For more information see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093153/hibernate-collectionofelements-eager-fetch-duplicates-elements)

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the equals and hashcode methods correctly and store in a Set rather than a Collection, it is less of an issue *unless* the volume of duplicates is excessive.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your getter `catalogImages()` does not follow Java Bean naming convention. I'm not sure, but it might confuse JPA provider somehow.
2. By using  `Collection<CatalogImage>` you've explicitly told JPA provider that **duplicates are allowed**. As it was already told, using `Set` instead of `Collection` solves duplicates-issue in most cases and allows avoiding `FetchType.EAGER` unless you really need it.

Comment: the getter is supposed to be `getCatalogImage`, the original posting of the code was a typo. As for switching to `Set` I understand that will eliminate duplicates from being added, but I don't understand why duplicates are being created from the jpa/hibernate created sql query itself.

Comment: @NKing253, from my pov its because of one2one relation between Store and CatalogGallery or because you're querying dataset of two Stores. Depend's on your sql schema. JPA is a "black box" and best way to find what's going on, is to see generated sql. For hibernate use option hibernate.show_sql http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional