# JPA unidirectional ManyToMany - duplicated positions in when retrieving list

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I had following entities in my project:

- `AccountGroup`
- `AccountItem`
- `AccountSegment`

With folowing relations:

- `AccountGroup` has `List<AccountItem>`
- `AccountItem` **had** `List<AccountSegment>`

and everything worked fine.

When I changed last relation to:

- `AccountItem` has `Set<AccountSegment>`

`AccountGroup` object read from database looks strange. If given `AccountItem` had three `AccountSegment`s, then I have three the same `AccountItem`s in `AccountGroup`.

A shot from debugger can possibly tell it better than I can:
[image: SS from debugger]

As you can see, `accountMapperItems` list has four positions instead of two. First pair is a duplicate each having the same variables. (second is similar, not shown on screenshot).

Below I paste entities code fragments:

```
class AccountGroup {
    ...
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "group")
    private List<AccountItem> accountMapperItems;
    ....
}

class AccountItem {
    ...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE })
    @JoinTable(
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="ACCOUNT_ITEM_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="SEGMENT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private Set<Segment> segmentSet;

    @ManyToOne
    private AccountGroup group;
    ...
}
```

`AccountSegment` does not have any links.

Does anyone know why is it retriving `accountMapperItems` list one position per `AccountSegment`?

The problem is not duplicate entries in jointable! I have double checked it.

**Update**

```
@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)
```

solved the case, further explanations are available in post mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure all your entities implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`. These methods are used by some collections (like Sets) to uniquely identify elements.

**Edit**: If that doesn't solve it, then I think the duplicates are most likely caused by the `FetchType.EAGER`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1093694/1464763) explains it well. Try removing the `FetchType.EAGER` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: After adding equals and hashcode methods to both objects `AccountSegment` and `AccountItem` behaviour remains the same. Both methods are based only on primary key.

Comment: Are you retrieving data through JPQL queries, or are you just using the collections getters?

Comment: I am retrieving only `AccountGroup` using entity manager method `find(AcountGroup.class, id)`

Comment: Thanks! `@Fetch (FetchMode.SELECT)` from the link you gave solved the case!